# Sort an array of pairs

Tags: java, arrays

Given a list of pairs of numbers e.g. [(1,4), (2,5), (7, 3),(4,6),(7,7)]. Find the longest sub-list that has the pairs sorted by the first entry in ascending order by the second in descending order. Answer for this task is [(2,5), (7, 3)].

I created the object 'Pair' with two fields: 'first' and 'second':

```
class Pair{
    int first;
    int second;
    public Pair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Next I created an array of the 'Pair' type and filled the arrays by the 'Pair' objects:

```
    Pair arrPair[] = new Pair[5];
    arrPair[0] = new Pair(1, 4);
    arrPair[1] = new Pair(2, 5);
    arrPair[2] = new Pair(7, 3);
    arrPair[3] = new Pair(4, 6);
    arrPair[4] = new Pair(7, 7);
```

As far as I understand next I should write some loop to compare the elements of arrPair[]. But I don't know how this loop should work and look and how I can get results and where.

Could you help me guys?

Comment: I think you have to use a modification of a well-known "longest increasing subsequence" problem

Comment: You could try creating a custom `Comparator<Pair>` or make `Pair` implement `Comparable<Pair>` and implement the desired comparison logic there.

Comment: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657951/the-longest-sublist-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may add three function to your Pair class.
The first one should be

```
isAscending() { 
   return this.first < this.second; 
}
```

the second one should be

```
isDescending() {
   return this.first > this.second;
}
```

the third one should be

```
range() {
   if(isAscending()) 
     return this.second - this.first;

   return this.first - this.second;
}
```

You may create two variables in order to host the longest sublist for ascending pair and for descending pair. Then, (1) you'll have to iterate over your array (2) determine if the current pair is ascending or descending (3) determine if the pair is longer than the previous max.

Example (more or less pseudo-code):

```
myCurrentLongestAscending = new Pair(0,0);
myCurrentLongestDecending = new Pair(0,0);

for (Pair currentPair : myPairs){
  if( currentPair.isAscending() && currentPair.range() > myCurrentLongestAscending.range()){
       myCurrentLongestAscending = currentPair;

  else if( currentPair.isDescending() && currentPair.range() > myCurrentLongestDecending .range()) {
       myCurrentLongestDecending = currentPair;
  }
}

myResult = [myCurrentLongestAscending, myCurrentLongestDecending];
```